# Installing ldid on linux for theos

Tags: ios, linux, jailbreak

I am completely new to linux and its shell. I am attempting to follow the tutorials at http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Getting_Started#NIC_Example to install Theos and deploy an application, however I am having issues with step 4

Download ldid to `$THEOS/bin:`

```
git clone git://git.saurik.com/ldid.git
cd ldid
git submodule update --init
./make.sh
cp -f ./ldid $THEOS/bin/ldid
```

The 1st command runs and I get the following output

```
Cloning into 'ldid'...
remote: Counting objects: 175, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (115/115), done.
remote: Total 175 (delta 93), reused 102 (delta 56)
Receiving objects: 100% (175/175), 50.31 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (93/93), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

the next command `cd ldid` executes and I am now inside `/home/MYNAME/ldid`
I run the next command and there is no output.

and finally this is where I suspect the error is. I run `./make.sh` and I get

```
+ g++ -o ldid ldid.cpp -I. -x c lookup2.c sha1.c
./make.sh: line 19: g++: command not found
```

I should mention I am on a VM running Fedora 20-1.

As suggested I installed gcc & g++ ran the `./make.sh` and still failed with

```
+ g++ -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -o ldid ldid.cpp -I. -x c lookup2.c sha1.c
g++: error: i386: No such file or directory
g++: error: x86_64: No such file or directory
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-arch’
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-arch’
```

Comment: ... did you install gcc & g++?

Comment: Yes I ran the command again and still resulted in the error.

Comment: I'm in the same position now.  Has ANYONE got a fix?

Comment: Are you on Mac or Linux? I was struggling and installed OS X and a VM and downloaded IosOpenDev and signed it with their ldid and it worked like a charm. Not sure if the same works on linux

Comment: Yea nope just checked and IosOpenDev is a package for Macs only, I also remember reading that the linux compiler lacks the -arch parameter or something along those lines and only the Mac versions support it.

Answer (score 3):

```
git clone https://github.com/daeken/ldid.git
cd ./ldid
./make.sh
```

Comment: It checks out another git project - the make.sh has been updated for Linux